# MVC 4 using Entity Framework 6 - View Data Getting retrieved but not being Rendered

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hello I have been doing MVC and am stuck in a surreal problem.

### **This is my Requirement:**

There will be images of few cities. Onclicking of these images the students from that particular cities must be retrieved and displayed in a different page.

### **Problem :**

The city is being retrieved using jqueryAjax on click, being sent to the controller, retrieved from the database and being forwarded to the SearchResults View, **But not rendering in the view(also the page is not redirecting to SearchResults from SearchByTerritory).**

Please help me I have searched a lot for this but still not found any answers.

I have created 2 pages(views) SearchByTerritory.cshtml - for displaying images and SearchResults.cshtml - for displaying the results and controllers for these views respectively.

The following is my code

**SearchByTerritory View:**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Search By Territory";
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.usaMap').click(function () {
        var address = $(this).attr("id");

        var url = "/Student/SearchByTerritory";
        var address = $(this).attr("id");
        $.post(url, { address: address }, function (data) {

        });

    })
});
</script>

<h2>SearchByTerritory</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<img src="~/Images/test1.gif" class="usaMap" id="Noida" alt="Noida" title="Noida" />
<img src="~/Images/test2.png" class="usaMap" id="Gurgaon" alt="Gurgaon" title="Gurgaon" />
<img src="~/Images/test3.png" class="usaMap" id="Mangalore" alt="Mangalore" title="Mangalore" />
//@Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "SearchByTerritory", new { address = "Noida" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/Images/USA.jpg\" />"));

}

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("See all Users", "Index")
</p>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SearchByTerritory()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchByTerritory(string address)
    {
        var students = from s in db.Students
                       select s;
        students = students.Where(s => s.Address.Contains(address));
        if (students != null && students.Count() > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.dbs = students.ToList();
            //return RedirectToAction("SearchResults", ViewBag.dbs);
            return View("SearchResults", students);
        }

        return View("SearchEmpty");
    }
```

**SearchResults View:**

```
<h2>Search Results</h2>
<fieldset>
<legend>Student</legend>
@foreach (NEWDigitalYearBookRK.Models.Student s in ViewBag.dbs as List<NEWDigitalYearBookRK.Models.Student>) 
{
    <div class="display-label">
        First Name
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @s.FirstName
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        Last Name
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @s.LastName
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        Age

    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @s.Age
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        Gender
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @s.Gender
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        Batch
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @s.Batch
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        Address
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @s.Address
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        Class
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @s.Class
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        School
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @s.School
    </div>

    <div class="display-label">
        Domicile
    </div>
    <div class="display-field">
        @s.Domicile
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you have some things right, but somethings are also wrong. My advice to young developers or if you are new to MVC, you have first to understand how web works, and then understand how the MVC framework really works and how does it map with the web.

Okay. I can give you here some hints, but you will have to debug and make it work.
You are using SearchByTerritory as a "post" method for an ajax call, and it returns a normal view! this doesn't work. You have couple of options here, but let me tell you the simpler option:

- add [HttpGet] method SearchResult, that accepts string id
- Edit your code in the searchbyterritory view this way (better way to use html helpers to render the url)

  <a href="/searchresult/noida"><img src="~/Images/test1.gif" class="usaMap" id="Noida" alt="Noida" title="Noida" /></a>
- comment the js code you have.
- in the searchresult action method, add your code to get the data and return the view.

You can later enhance the code to use ajax calls, and even maybe display the result in the same page as in a single page application would do. but you gotta understand how that works.

Comment: hey i used clickable image by using Html.Raw and passed value through query string. But its not that secure so i want to implement in a more secure manner. Could you help me

Comment: what is the security issue you are worried about.

Comment: like anyone can type through QS and retrieve data

Comment: @Khudairy you said "SearchByTerritory as a "post" method for an ajax call, and it returns a normal view! this doesn't work." so how can i send html data to my controller ??? This might seem a noob question but im curious

Comment: @user3658071, am not sure how much you have worked with ajax calls before so if you haven't first of all check the w3c school tutorial. when am working on mvc project, i create a web api service that receives json data, and return json data to my page, in the success function i parse the json data returned to render my html. you can also check out how to return a partial view

Comment: for your security concern. yes that is valid, but that is almost valid even if you use another way. So you should validate the data entered by the user, like make sure your code doesn't break if user sends an empty string, or invalid id, and make sure the user is cannot inject something into ur databse query (if you are using EF i think u r safe)